# Python-3.x - Converting a string representation of a bytearray back to a string

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x

The back-story here is a little verbose, but basically I want to take a string like `b'\x04\x0e\x1d'` and cast it back into a bytearray.

I am working on a basic implementation of a one time pad, where I take a plaintext `A` and shared key `B` to generate a ciphertext `C` accoring to the equation `A⊕B=C`. Then I reverse the process with the equation `C⊕B=A`.

I've already found plenty of python3 functions to encode strings as bytes and then xor the bytes, such as the following:

```
def xor_strings(xs, ys):
    return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)).encode()
```

A call to `xor_strings()` then returns a bytearray:

```
print( xor_strings("foo", "bar"))
```

But when I print it to the screen, what I'm shown is actually a string. So I'm assuming that python is just calling some `str()` function on the bytearray, and I get something that looks like the following:

`b'\x04\x0e\x1d'`

Herein lies the problem. I want to create a new bytearray from that string. Normally I would just call `decode()` on the bytearray. But if I enter `b'\x04\x0e\x1d' as input, python sees it as a string, not a bytearray!

How can I take a string like `b'\x04\x0e\x1d'` as user input and cast it back into a bytearray?

Comment: Can't you store the result of calling "join" into a variable? xor_strings already returns a byte array.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `b'\x04\x0e\x1d'` is not a string, it's a byte array. Or do you want the user to enter "b'\x04\x0e\x1d'" into a textbox?

Comment: @EnricoBorba The problem is that after I encipher my message, I want to print it to the screen so I can copy it and send it to a friend. Then they should be able to take that string, paste it as input, and the program should be able to recognize that string as a bytearray again, not as a string

Comment: That's not how you would send bytes to a friend, at least I strongly discourage it. Use a common transfer encoding like base64 for such a task.

Comment: @Tomalak the latter. I want to supply "b'\x04\x0e\x1d'" to the input() function and be able to have the program parse that string somehow back into a bytearray

Comment: Nope. Send base64; the recipient can copy and paste that easily. It's a resilient format that virtually every environment on the planet can decode back into bytes. Python has the [base64 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) for this purpose.

Comment: @Tomalak well, I'm now convinced that you are correct and that base64 is the way to go. But even if the question is a weird one, I'm still curious as to how you'd take "b'\x04\x0e\x1d'" from a textbox and convert it to a bytearray. Is there an easy/built in way? Or would you basically have to parse the string and convert each byte

Comment: Yes, I would write a loop that steps through the string four characters at a time and then convert each part into a number, building a byte array as I go. It's fundamentally the same thing that a base64 decoder does, but base64 has been made for this exact purpose, it solves many problems that you did not even think of and as a built-in module it's basically free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, use base64 to send binary data in text form.

```
import base64

def xor_strings(xs, ys):
    return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)).encode()

# ciphertext is bytes
ciphertext = xor_strings("foo", "bar")
# >>> b'\x04\x0e\x1d'

# ciphertext_b64 is *still* bytes, but only "safe" ones (in the printable ASCII range)
ciphertext_b64 = base64.encodebytes(ciphertext)
# >>> b'BA4d\n'
```

Now we can transfer the bytes:

```
# ...we could interpret them as ASCII and print them somewhere
safe_string = ciphertext_b64.decode('ascii')
# >>> BA4d

# ...or write them to a file (or a network socket)
with open('/tmp/output', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(ciphertext_b64)
```

And the recipient can retrieve the original message by:

```
# ...reading bytes from a file (or a network socket)
with open('/tmp/output', 'rb') as f:
    ciphertext_b64_2 = f.read()

# ...or by reading bytes from a string
ciphertext_b64_2 = safe_string.encode('ascii')
# >>> b'BA4d\n'

# and finally decoding them into the original nessage
ciphertext_2 = base64.decodestring(ciphertext_b64_2)
# >>> b'\x04\x0e\x1d'
```

Of course when it comes to writing bytes to a file or to the network, encoding them as base64 first is superfluous. You can write/read the ciphertext directly if it's the only file content. Only if the ciphertext it is part of a higher structure (JSON, XML, a config file...) encoding it as base64 becomes necessary again.

A note on the use of the words "decode" and "encode".

- To *encode* a string means to turn it from its abstract meaning ("a list of characters") into a storable representation ("a list of bytes"). The exact result of this operation depends on the byte encoding that is being used. For example:

  - ASCII encoding maps one character to one byte (as a trade-off it can't map all characters that can exist in a Python string).
  - UTF-8 encoding maps one character to 1-5 bytes, depending on the character.
- To *decode* a byte array means turning it from "a list of bytes" back into "a list of characters" again. This of course requires prior knowledge of what the byte encoding originally was.

`ciphertext_b64` above is a list of bytes and is represented as `b'BA4d\n'` on the Python console.

Its string equivalent, `safe_string`, looks very similar `'BA4d\n'` when printed to the console due to the fact that base64 is a sub-set of ASCII.

The data *types* however are still fundamentally different. Don't let the console output deceive you.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to that final question only.

```
>>> type(b'\x04\x0e\x1d')
<class 'bytes'>
>>> bytearray(b'\x04\x0e\x1d')
bytearray(b'\x04\x0e\x1d')
>>> type(bytearray(b'\x04\x0e\x1d'))
<class 'bytearray'>
```